# Hilt - Fatal Exception when passing object into ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am updating my app to use Hilt but am seeing a crash when passing a value into my viewmodel.

`MainActivity`

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            XGarageTheme {
                XGarageApp()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun XGarageApp() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController, startDestination = "main_menu") {
        composable(route = "main_menu") {
            SplashScreen {
                navController.navigate("main_menu_screen")
            }
        }
        composable(route = "main_menu_screen") {
            val viewModel: MainMenuViewModel = viewModel()
            MainMenuScreen(viewModel.photoGalleryState.value, viewModel.itemMenuState.value)
        }
        composable(route = "details_screen") {
            DetailsScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

`MainMenuViewModel`

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainMenuViewModel @Inject constructor(galleryRepository: MenuPhotoGalleryRepository) : ViewModel() {
private val menuItemDataSource: MenuItemListLocal = MenuItemListLocal()
private val menuItemRepository: MenuItemRepository = MenuItemRepository(menuItemDataSource)

val photoGalleryState: MutableState<List<String>> = mutableStateOf(emptyList())
val itemMenuState: MutableState<List<MenuItem>> = mutableStateOf(emptyList())

init {
    photoGalleryState.value = galleryRepository.getImageGalleryList()
    itemMenuState.value = menuItemRepository.getMenuItemsList()
}
```

}

*(Note: Everything will be injected but I wanted to solve this issue first)*

`MenuPhotoGalleryRepository`

```
class MenuPhotoGalleryRepository @Inject constructor() {
    private val imageGallery = listOf(
        "file:///android_asset/images/cars/x1.jpg",
        "file:///android_asset/images/cars/x2.jpg",
        "file:///android_asset/images/cars/x3.jpg",
    )

    init {

    }

    fun getImageGalleryList(): List<String> {
        return imageGallery
    }
}
```

`Note: I added the` init `block to try and resolve the issue, it didn't change the error displayed`

`My Application Class`

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class XMissionXApplication @Inject constructor() : Application() {

}
```

The error that I get is:
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.elnimijogames.porschegarage, PID: 29180 java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.xgames.xgarage.ui.mainmenu.MainMenuViewModel`

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.xgames.xgarage.ui.mainmenu.MainMenuViewModel.<init> []
```

If I remove the `Singleton` keyword and the constructor for `MenuPhotoGalleryRepository` I instead get the error:
`MenuPhotoGalleryRepository cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.`

If I do not pass anything into the ViewModel everything works without crashing... :/

I am using Hilt 2.46.1 - My gradle files look like this:

```
// Hilt
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46.1")
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.46.1")
```

The issue as I see it is to do with the class being passed into the MainMenuViewModel which I think should have its own provider but I'm not sure how to resolve this. I don't see that a `module` is required with Hilt, but perhaps I'm wrong?

Any help will be gratefully appreciated!

----UPDATE----

I added a module class as follows:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesMenuPhotoGalleryRepository(): MenuPhotoGalleryRepository {
        return MenuPhotoGalleryRepository()
    }
}
```

I also removed any annotations from `MenuPhotoGalleryRepository`

I'm still however receiving the exact same error, i.e.

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.elnimijogames.porschegarage, PID: 6133
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.elnimijogames.xgarage.ui.mainmenu.MainMenuViewModel
......
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.elnimijogames.xgarage.ui.mainmenu.MainMenuViewModel.<init>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val viewModel: MainMenuViewModel = hiltViewModel()
```

(make sure you type hiltViewModel() in camelcase)

Instead of:

```
val viewModel: MainMenuViewModel = viewModel()
```

You'll also need the hilt navigation dependencies added for this

Comment: Hi @Kristy. Thanks for your response. Do you mean this one?

`implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0")` - I can't see anything about the navigation dependencies on the Hilt page.

Answer (score 0):

Providing my own answer since there were several changes I needed to make.

A few highlights:

1. Yes, I needed to use 'hiltViewModel'
2. I had to update my dependencies to do this.
3. I had to add a module, in the right location with the `installIn` annotation.
4. I had to remove any annotations from the injected class, i.e from the `MenuPhotoGalleryRepository`. This is because Dagger handles this itself.

Below are the files. I hope this helps someone else.

These were all of the `hilt` lines I added to `build.gradle`

```
// Hilt
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46.1'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.46.1'
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0")
kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1")
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
```

*NOTE: It's worth noting that, this was correct for me at the time of writing. When I've looked at examples where people are using older versions, things are quite different as the product seems to be evolving quite quickly.*

I added an `Application` class as Hilt requires this. This contains a `HiltAndroidApp` annotation.

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MissionXApplication @Inject constructor() : Application() {

}
```

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` file I added the name field.

```
<application
    android:name=".XMissionXApplication"
```

In the `MainActivity` file, I added the `AndroidEntryPoint` annotation

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
```

My `ViewModel` is also declared here but as a `HiltViewModel`

```
composable(route = "main_menu_screen") {
    val viewModel: MainMenuViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    MainMenuScreen(viewModel.photoGalleryState.value, viewModel.itemMenuState.value)
}
```

My `ViewModel` is annotated. Ignore the fact that this is mixed as I wanted to resolve this issue before injecting everything else... the main point is the annotation at the top and the `Inject constructor`

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainMenuViewModel @Inject constructor(galleryRepository: MenuPhotoGalleryRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val menuItemDataSource: MenuItemListLocal = MenuItemListLocal()
    //private val galleryRepository: MenuPhotoGalleryRepository = MenuPhotoGalleryRepository.getInstance()
    private val menuItemRepository: MenuItemRepository = MenuItemRepository(menuItemDataSource)

    val photoGalleryState: MutableState<List<String>> = mutableStateOf(emptyList())
    val itemMenuState: MutableState<List<MenuItem>> = mutableStateOf(emptyList())

     init {
        photoGalleryState.value = galleryRepository.getImageGalleryList()
        itemMenuState.value = menuItemRepository.getMenuItemsList()
     }
}
```

The injected `MenuPhotoGalleryRepository` needs no annotations at all. This is important. A provider instead will be required in a module class.

The final point was that I needed to add an `AppModule` (or whatever name works for you) in the same location as the applicable code, i.e. you may have multiple modules so add this to the same location that your code resides. I added mine into a `di` package.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesMenuPhotoGalleryRepository(): MenuPhotoGalleryRepository {
        return MenuPhotoGalleryRepository()
    }
}
```

Note: The `ViewModelComponent` is the scope for what is being provided.

I hope this helps you if you face similar issues!